# Compiler that adds machine info to binary

Tags: identity, compiler, serial

Wanted to ask if there is any compiler (any known programming language) that is actually encoding machine data into binary, so it is possible to detect the machine where the program has been compiled (e.g. serial, MAC etc.)?

Comment: I don’t know if any compilers encode any information that can uniquely identify the machine on which it was compiled. But some commonly used compilers can leave  plenty of information about the machine. See: [What evidence does a compiled file leave behind?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/236519/235964)